# jsPDF Autotable Images Gray and Washed out When multiple images

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

When I use jSPDF-Autotable to create a table on my PDF some of the images come out gray and washed out.  It looks like some of the images are coming out fine and some of them are overlapping on themselves.

I am using files that are stored in firebase storage.  I download them and then turn them into base64 files and try to add them to my PDF.  The first ones add fine and then some of them always end up washed out.   Please any help is appreciated!

```
    componentDidMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)

    function toDataURL(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                callback(reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();
    }






    const { item } = this.state;
    console.log(item.files)
    const images = []

    item.files.map((l) => { images.push({ key: l.key, type: 'photo', url: l.fileLink, b64: '' }) });
    item.lineItems.map((l) => { images.push({ key: l.key, type: 'photo', url: l.imageThumb.fileLink, b64: '' }) });




    images.map(async (l, i) => {
        const url = l.url;

        toDataURL(url, (dataUrl) => {
            l.b64 = dataUrl;
        })


        if (i + 1 === images.length) {
            this.setState({ creating: false })
        }

    })




    this.setState({ images })


}



createPDF = async () => {

    d.autoTable({
        startY: 3.9, margin: 1, pageBreak: 'auto', showHead: false,
        body: images.map((l, i) => {
            const index = i + 1;
            const even = index % 2 == 0;
            const color = even === true ? [200, 200, 200] : [255, 255, 255];
            const title = [{ content: `${l.url}`, meta: { key: l.key, img: l.b64 } }]
            return ([...title])
        })

        ,
        columns: [
            { header: 'Test', },
            { header: 'Test', },
        ],

        didDrawCell: async (data) => {
            if (data.cell.raw !== undefined) {

                console.log(data);

                if (data.section === 'body') {
                    console.log("ADD IMAGE")
                    data.row.height = 2

                    const ww = d.getImageProperties(data.cell.raw.meta.img).width;
                    const wh = d.getImageProperties(data.cell.raw.meta.img).height;
                    const ratio = ww / wh;


                    d.addImage(data.cell.raw.meta.img, 'PNG', data.cell.x + .2, data.cell.y, 1.75 * ratio, 1.75, `${data.cell.raw.meta.key}`, 'FAST');


                }


            }
        },



    });

}
```

[image: PDF WASHED]

Here are some of the errors I am getting. In my console.

[image]

Comment: Even when I remove that line it happens when I have more than one photo.  That color is to change the background on even row indexes.  It should only affect every other.  If I have 3 photos the first 2 get affected, if I have 5 photos the first 4 photos get affected. So lost.  This does not happen on images that were uploaded through react-dropzone, but only images that I take a screenshot of with arcgis api.

Comment: I'm starting to believe it has to be something that is being produced by the dataUrl from the takeScreenshot() function of arcgis api.  The most odd thing is that it appears that jsPDF is trying to put multiple images on top of each other resulting in the washed out graphic.

Comment: To make it even more confusing.  If I only pic one of those three images and add the same image to multiple places on the PDF there is no discoloration.

Comment: I was able to change the aliases for each one and it still does not work. I was able to take a screenshot of the console.log errors I am getting when I create the PDF.  Mayber there is some insight there.

Answer (score 0):

Well here you go for anyone else that runs into this. Once you have your data url from arcgis api use this function.

```
function getDataUri(url) {
                    return new Promise(resolve => {
                        var image = new Image();
                        image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous'); //getting images from external domain

                        image.onload = function () {
                            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                            canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
                            canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;

                            //next three lines for white background in case png has a transparent background
                            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                            ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';  /// set white fill style
                            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

                            resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
                        };

                        image.src = url;
                    })
                }
```